# Is there utility in a boolean function that flags the set of integers?

Tags: propositional-calculus, integers

I'm working on a math that might allow defining a differentiable function using elementary expressions which yields a 1 if a real number is an integer, and a 0 otherwise. I'm just curious if there might be any utility to such a function to have some idea of how much it's worth exploring or otherwise would appreciate any feedback about further avenues of research.

Thanks!

Comment: This function cannot be differentiable. You can write it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2n}(\pi x)$, but it has little use AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Yves, if it were differentiable might that effect its utility?

Comment: It IS NOT differentiable if you prefer.

Comment: Yes I understand and was not referring to your example, but I am studying numbers I defined that are neither real nor imaginary so just asked a hypothetical question.

Comment: I was referring to your function. It is not differentiable, full stop.

Comment: I'm curious, even though I said I'm not working with reals or imaginary numbers, but novel numbers I just made up, is there a technical reason that that should be the case? I'm asking because I am trying to write a paper on this and I suppose such feedback would help with clarity.